# SQL Loader isn't inserting data

Tags: sql-loader

I'm pretty new to using SQL, so I'm sorry if this is a simple mistake. Basically I need to load some data into a table. However, when I try to use sql loader to insert data into the table it doesn't get inserted, but no errors come up to indicate that anything went wrong.

Table:

```
create table Test(var char(3), var2 char(10), var3 number(7,2), 
var4 char(3),primary key (var));
```

This is my control file (Test1.ctl):

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
REPLACE INTO TABLE Test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'" TRAILING NULLCOLS
(var, var2, var3, var4 terminated by whitespace)
BEGINDATA
'123','test',12345,'321'
'321','test2',54321,null
```

I also tried using a separate .csv file to load the data instead of BEGINDATA, but the same thing happens with both methods.

Basically from the command prompt when I try to load the data, this happens:

```
[******** ~]$ sqlldr user_name Test1.ctl
Password:******

SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Sun Mar 26 14:01:21 2017

[******** ~]$
```

Then when I go to sqlplus to check the table, it's empty.

```
SQL> desc Test;
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------------
VAR                                       NOT NULL CHAR(3)
VAR2                                               CHAR(10)
VAR3                                               NUMBER(7,2)
VAR4                                               CHAR(3)

SQL> select * from Test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

I can't figure out why it won't get loaded into the table.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: show the log file please

Answer (score 0):

Version 10 is a pretty old release!!

I cannot reproduce your problem in 12c. You should get one row loaded; the second row fails because it's attempting to load the string "null" which is 4 characters into a CHAR(3)

```
 sqlldr scott test1.ctl
Password:

SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Mar 27 10:04:06 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  1 Row successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test1.log
for more information about the load.


 cat test1.log

SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Mar 27 10:04:06 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   test1.ctl
Data File:      test1.ctl
  Bad File:     test1.bad
  Discard File:  none specified

 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional

Table TEST, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: REPLACE
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
VAR                                 FIRST     *   ,  O(') CHARACTER            
VAR2                                 NEXT     *   ,  O(') CHARACTER            
VAR3                                 NEXT     *   ,  O(') CHARACTER            
VAR4                                 NEXT     *  WHT O(') CHARACTER            

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table TEST, column VAR4.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."TEST"."VAR4" (actual: 4, maximum: 3)


Table TEST:
  1 Row successfully loaded.
  1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                  66048 bytes(64 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             2
Total logical records rejected:         1
Total logical records discarded:        0

Run began on Mon Mar 27 10:04:06 2017
Run ended on Mon Mar 27 10:04:08 2017

Elapsed time was:     00:00:02.68
CPU time was:         00:00:00.03
```